# "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored human’s, appeared..."

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

My friend wrote a sentence that goes:

> Aliens, whose appearance mirrored human’s, appeared...

I corrected it to *mirrored humans’*, while another friend said that the apostrophe is unnecessary, and it can be *mirrored humans*, with the rest of the sentence intact.

I think mine is correct, but I don’t know enough grammar rules to justify it. What is the correct usage here, and why?

Comment: Can you format your question so it is clear how your answer differs from your other friend's? For example, by using double quotation marks to differentiate them from apostrophes.

Comment: I don't see any need for the genitive marker here. It simply means they looked like humans. Note that you could say "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored that of humans, appeared". Again, no genitive marker required. Incidentally, why is the relative clause written as a supplementary one rather than an integrated one?

Comment: The usual way of expressing this idea is "... mirrored *that of* humans" or less formally, "...who looked human".

Comment: It can mirror a human or mirror a human's appearance.

Comment: "The aliens' appearance mirrored humans' appearance." "Jill's handbag resembled Jean's." " The boys' average height was greater than the girls'."  "Birds' speed of flight exceeds bats'. " (Though as TimR says, the of-genitive is more common here: "The flying speed of [most] birds is greater than that of bats."

Comment: @Stuart F That makes "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored a human" possible (but which human?) I'd avoid this. // And "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored that of a human" mixes plural and singular rather messily.

Comment: More simply "whose appearance seems human" side-steps the problem.

Comment: No one addressed who's editing who: "**I corrected it** ... , while another friend **said**." If editor, you decide and stay consistent. Otherwise, I said friend said website said.

Comment: Aside from the main issue of whether an appearance can mirror a human or only another appearance, there is a stylistic question of how much appearance you really want in a sentence. Certainly, it sounds utterly ridiculous to me to say that, “aliens whose appearance mirrored humans’ appearance, appeared” – that’s three separate _appear_ in one sentence. “Aliens who looked just like humans appeared” is much more natural.

Comment: I think in most circumstances I would cut this into two separate sentences. *"Aliens appeared... . Their appearance mirrored that of humans."* I see little benefit into combining these two into the single sentence *"Aliens, whose appearance mirrored humans', appeared..."* . I find these two commas much more disruptive for the reader than a clean sentence break.

Comment: @BillJ I think it was written as a supplementary to give pause during the reading of the sentence via the comma.

Comment: @Ootington  When commas surround a relative clause, it means that it is semantically non-defining. And in speech the intonation break means the same thing.

Comment: I like it the way you wrote it, although I would have omitted all the commas ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"The appearance of the aliens mirrored the appearance **of** humans", so it should be **humans'** with an apostrophe.

Comment: That was my reading of the sentence, but I think you can parse it a different way, so that there's no possessive.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I tend to agree with Kate here. But I hope you and I are agreed that the "human's" in the original question is definitely wrong!

Comment: @Tony, yes I agree the original is wrong, and Kate is most likely correct.  The other reading is somewhat unnatural to me.

Comment: I can't see any reason for "humans" to be a genitive NP. It makes no sense to say "Aliens. whose appearance mirrored humans' appearance, appeared".  It simply means they looked like humans.

Comment: The aliens can mirror humans directly, not just their appearance! Then they are the direct object, no genitive.

Comment: @BillJ: I disagree that your example makes no sense; it's just very clumsy. The reason to use a genitive NP is that it gives better parallelism (cf "The appearance of the aliens mirrored the appearance of the humans"). But it works without, too.

Comment: @psmears Aliens may match humans but appearances don't. A genitive NP determines the head of a matrix NP, the head being either overt or covert, in this case the latter, which is interpreted here as "humans' appearance" which makes no sense. The genitive case is wrong. Better would be "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored that of humans, appeared" See also Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment to the OP..

Comment: @BillJ: Yes, there are too many "appear"s there in the original, hence "clumsy" as I say. And it doesn't help that two different meanings are being used ("appearance"="becoming visible" vs "appearance"="they way they look"). But I don't see how you can say "humans' appearance" makes no sense and yet accept "that \[=appearance] of humans"; one might be preferable but they mean the same, surely?

Answer (score 15):

Your friend's sentence is indeed not grammatical English.  However, *all* of the variations below can be correct, with subtle differences in meaning:

> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored **humans'** [appearance], appeared..."

Here, "humans'" with an apostrophe is a plural possessive form, modifying an implicit "appearance".  That is, the appearance of the aliens mirrors the appearance of humans.

> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored **the humans'** [appearance], appeared..."

Same as above, except with a definite article.  This feels slightly less idiomatic to me than omitting the article entirely, but not strictly speaking incorrect.  To my ear, it carries a vague implication that the speaker is perhaps not human.

> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored **a human's** [appearance], appeared..."

This is the same as both of the above, except that the appearance of the aliens now mirrors the appearance of a (grammatically) singular human, representing a generic member of the human race.  (Compare with e.g. "A human is a featherless biped.")

> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored that **of humans**, appeared..."
> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored the appearance of humans, appeared..."

This is basically the same as the first variation above, except using an of-genitive instead of an s-genitive.  With the s-genitive we could elide "appearance" entirely, but with the of-genitive we need to replace it with the pronoun "that" if we don't want to repeat it.

Instead of "of humans", you could also use "of the humans" or "of a human" here, analogously to variations 2 and 3 above.

> "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored **humans**, appeared..."

Here, "humans" is a simple plural noun acting as the direct object of the verb "mirror".  That is, the appearance of the aliens literally mirrors humans, not the *appearance of* humans.

This is, to my ear, a somewhat unusual way to use the verb "mirror", but I would stop short of calling it incorrect.  Certainly it's perfectly understandable in context, and no more metaphorical than the (IME) more typical usage in the previous variations.

Again, instead of "humans", you *could* also use "the humans" or even "a human" here, although for me personally "mirrored a human" starts to sound just a little bit awkward, evoking mental images of a single human (who?!) standing in front of mirror-skinned aliens.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Conventionally, both "human" and "humans" should be correct, but you have to keep in mind if you decide to go with the singular form, don't forget an "a" before "human".

"Aliens, whose appearance mirrored that of a human"
"Aliens, whose appearance mirrored a human's"

Comment: The problem with this interpretation is that it suggests that there is a particular human that all the aliens resemble.

Comment: @user888379: I don't think it suggests that interpretation. It certainly *allows* that interpretation, but I can't imagine anyone *actually* misunderstanding it that way.

Answer (score 3):

I’ll play the Devil’s advocate here . . . Possession is unnecessary. <sub><sup>(sorry!)</sup></sub>

> **mirror** *v.*
> **3.a.** *transitive*. To reflect or reproduce accurately; to represent or express (an idea, emotion, etc.). Also: to duplicate,
> imitate. Occasionally with *back*.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English
> Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

So:

> *Aliens, whose appearance **accurately reflected** humans, appeared . . .*
>
> *Aliens, whose appearance **mirrored** humans, appeared . . .*

Comment: It should be possessive, because the appearance mirrors that of humans (the appearance of humans, not humans themselves).

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's use of the apostrophe is wrong indeed.

There are 2 acceptable ways to fixing this:

1. "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored humans', appeared..."
2. "Aliens, whose appearance mirrored **that of** humans, appeared...

You're correct, but your friends aren't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What the bot said, but wouldn't it be "whose appearance mirrored that of humans"? Or possibly (though unusually) "whose appearances mirrored those of humans"? It's currently a [singular] appearance that's shared by lot of individuals.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere Ah yes, you're right. Appearance is definitely singular here. Thank you for that.